# Find the number of ordered triplets $(a, b, c)$ of positive integers such that $30a + 50b + 70c < 343$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

> Find the number of ordered triplets $(a, b, c)$ of positive integers such that $30a + 50b + 70c < 343$

**My Attempt**:

$c$ cannot be $5$ since $70 \times 5 > 343$.

It can't be $4$ either since if we put $c = 4$, we get $30a + 50b < 63$, which would mean there are no positive integer solutions for at least one of $a$ or $b$.

So, there are 3 options for $c$.

Proceeding similarly, we will get that $b = 1,2,3,4$ or there are $4$ options for b.

Similarly, there are $7$ options for $c$.

Since any value of $a$ can be paired with any value of $b$ and $c$, we get  $3 \times 4 \times 7=84$ total triplets which is not the answer

Comment: What is the answer in your book?

Comment: "Since any value of a can be paired with any value of b and c" this right here is the mistake. If we have $c=3$ we reduce to $30a + 50b < 133$. However we need to now be careful we don't choose too large a value for $b$. In your attempt you assume $b=4$ works but this isn't so

Comment: "It can't be 4 either since if we put c=4, we get 30a+50b=63" No, you get $30a + 50b < 63$, "which would mean there are no positive integer solutions for either a or b."  No, there are plenty of positive values for $a$ if you take zero or less values for $c$ and vice versa.  There aren't any positive value pairs for *both* $a$ and $b$.  Be careful with your language.

Comment: @fleablood $a,b,c$ must all be positive integers as per the initial question

Comment: @lioness99a, The solution requires that $a,b$ and $c$ be positive.  If the OP's claim that there is no positive solution for *either* a *or* b were true, then that would be impossible.  But the OP's claim is *not* true.  There are positive solutions for $a$ and there are positive solutions for $b$.  So to show this is impossible the OP needs to make a *different* claim.  The different claim should have been "There are no *simultaneous* positive solutions for *both* $a$ and $b$".  Language is important.

Comment: The minimum sum is $150$ so you can use that to decrease the number of cases

Comment: But this leads to considering solutions where $a,b,c$ can be zero

Comment: @fleablood I think we all knew what OP meant...

Comment: "I think we all knew what OP meant... "  Of course we did.  But that doesn't mean the OP wasn't being careless with numbers.  And carelessness leads to errors as WaveX points out.

Comment: @fleablood Ill take care from next time onward. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that if $c=3$ you need $30a+50b \lt 133$.  In that case $b$ can only be $1$ or $2$.  If $b=2$ you must have $a=1$, while if $b=1$ you can have $a=1$ or $2$.  The choices are not independent, so you cannot multiply.

You can just continue the casework.  There are not too many cases for $b,c$.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in saying that $c=1,2,3$ but this is where you then made the mistake. We need to consider each of these cases separately

When $c=3$, we have $30a+50b<133$. Here, $b$ cannot be greater than $3$ as $50\times3=150>133$. So we have $b=1,2$.

When $b=1$, then we have $30a<83$ meaning $a<2.766\ldots$ so $a=1,2$ are the integer solutions

When $b=2$, then we have $30a<33$ meaning $a<1.1$ so $a=1$ is the only integer solution

So, for $c=3$, we have $3$ possible solutions:

\begin{align}(a,b,c)&=(1,2,3)\\
&=(1,1,3)\\
&=(2,1,3)\end{align}

Now we can do similar things for $c=2$ and $c=1$

Answer (score -1):

$(x^3+x^6+x^9+x^{12}+...x^{33})\cdot (x^5+x^{10}+x^{15}+x^{20}+x^{30}) \cdot (x^7+x^{14}+x^{21}+x^{28})$

Expand the above using geometric progression sum, and then find the sum of coefficients of $x^k$ where $k\leq 34$